# Spring: does "rails server" not start spring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring-gem

I'm just wondering: doesn't `rails server` start spring? It seems, that only `rake` or `rails console` starts spring. Is this normal behaviour, or do I have something misconfigured?

Answer (score 4):

I just confused too. Then I find this.

[here explained when spring will start](https://github.com/rails/spring#rails-console-rails-generate-rails-runner)

> rails console, rails generate, rails runner
>
> These execute the rails command you already know and love. If you run
>   a different sub command (e.g. rails server) then spring will
>   automatically pass it through to the underlying rails executable
>   (without the speed-up).

Comment: Thank you. Would be interesting though why `rails server` doesn't fire up spring? I usually start my server first, then some time later I need the console or generate a scaffold or something.